# Bind a value between a parent and a child element where child element is created using javascript

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

Using Polymer, does anyone know how to bind a value between a parent and a child element?

Below is my attempt however it doesn't work.

Note: `child-component` needs to be created using JavaScript.

```html
<dom-module id="host-component">
  <template>
      <div>{{sharedValue}}</div>
      <div id="childComponentContainer">
          <!-- CHILD-COMPONENT GETS CREATED HERE -->
      </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({is:'host-component',
        properties:{
            sharedValue:{
                type: String,
                notify:true,
                observer: 'sharedValueChanged'
            }
        },
        attached: function(){
            var newElement = document.createElement('child-component');
            Polymer.dom(this.$.childComponentContainer).appendChild(newElement);
        },
        sharedValueChanged:function(d){
            console.log(d, ", said the child");
        }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="child-component">
  <template>
      <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{sharedValue}}" />
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({is:'child-component',
        properties:{
            sharedValue:{
                type: String,
                notify:true,
                reflectToAttribute:true,
            }
        },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: there is a similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615549/data-binding-in-a-dinamically-inserted-polymer-element?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After re-reading Polymer's documentation (many times) I found a section about [how Two-way data-binding events work](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path) where by on each change Polymer fires a DOM event. From this I came up with the **work around** below.

You'll notice this version also has two way binding so the host can change the child's value and the child can change the host's value!

```html
<dom-module id="host-component">
  <template>
      <div>Host: <span>{{sharedValue}}</span></div>
      <div>Host: <span><input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{sharedValue}}" /></span></div>
      <div id="childComponentContainer">
          <!-- CHILD-COMPONENT GETS CREATED HERE -->
      </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({is:'host-component',
        properties:{
            sharedValue:{
                type: String,
                notify:true,
                value: "Unchanged",
                observer: 'sharedValueChanged'
            }
        },
        attached: function(){
            this.$.childComponent = document.createElement('child-component');
            var host = this;

            //Listens to the child's sharedValue. When changed it will update host's sharedValue.
            this.$.childComponent.addEventListener("shared-value-changed", function(e){
                host.sharedValue = this.sharedValue;
            });
            Polymer.dom(this.$.childComponentContainer).appendChild(this.$.childComponent);
        },

        //Observes the hosts's sharedValue. When changed it will update child's sharedValue.
        sharedValueChanged: function(value){
            if (this.$.childComponent) {
                this.$.childComponent.sharedValue = value;
            }
        }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>




<dom-module id="child-component">
  <template>
      <div>Child: <span>{{sharedValue}}</span></div>
      <div>Child: <span><input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{sharedValue}}" /></span></div>

  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({is:'child-component',
        properties:{
            sharedValue:{
                type: String,
                notify:true,
                value:"Unchanged",
                reflectToAttribute:true,
            }
        }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```