# Listening children's property change notifier using prototype's listeners property in Polymer not working

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Why will not this work ?
I am trying to use `notify` and `listeners` together. Am I missing something ?

```
Polymer({
  is: 'x-child',

  properties: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      value: '',
      notify: true
    }
  }
});

Polymer({
  is: 'x-dad',

  listeners: {
    'message-changed': '_onMessageReceived'
  },

  _onMessageReceived: function (e) {
    alert('child sent a message');
  }
});
```

**scenario**

```
var d = document.createElement('x-dad');
var c = document.createElement('x-child');
d.appendChild(c);
c.message = 'new';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In devguide it writes:

> When the property changes, the element fires a **non-bubbling** DOM event to indicate those changes to interested hosts.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#change-notification-protocol

It means that event listeners are invoked only on the `x-child` element, but not on its ancestors. This may be what you are missing.

Answer (score -1):

In the scenario you provided, how is Polymer supposed to know how to bind x-dad's message property with x-child's message property?

If you declare x-child in the html, to relate the 2 items, you will have to declare something like:

```html
<x-child message={{message}}></x-child>
```

As for getting your current setup to work, maybe consider something similar to what is used in [Bind a value between a parent and a child element where child element is created using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685452/bind-a-value-between-a-parent-and-a-child-element-where-child-element-is-created)