# Add a "dynamic" element with data-binding to my polymer-element

Tags: javascript, html, binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

For days I try to feed Polymer with some "dynamic" elements :) Unfortunately without success...
My goal is to get an element added during runtime and fill it with content by polymer-data-binding (in a "natural" polymer-way. Without a workaround as suggested in another [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615549/data-binding-in-a-dynamically-inserted-polymer-element).)

Please take a look at the code in this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/mkappeller/ken9Lzc7/) or at the bottom of this question.
I really hope anyone out there is able to help me out.
It would also help to know if there will be a way to do this some day in the future...?

---

```js
window.addEventListener("WebComponentsReady", function() {
  var myAppModule = document.getElementById("my-app");
  var myApp = document.getElementsByTagName("my-app")[0];

  myApp.set("global", {
    text: "Init"
  });
});
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">

<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <paper-input label="global.text" value="{{global.text}}"></paper-input>
    <paper-button raised id="addHeadline">Add Headline</paper-button>
    <paper-button raised id="changeText">Change Text</paper-button>
    <p>global.text: &lt;{{global.text}}&gt;</p>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "my-app",
      properties: {
        global: {}
      },
      ready: function() {
        this.count = 0;

        this.$.addHeadline.addEventListener("click", () => {

          var myApp = Polymer.dom(document.getElementById("my-app"));

          var t = myApp.node.childNodes[1];

          var heading = document.createElement("h1");
          heading.textContent = "{{global.text}}";

          // Append to my-app
          Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(heading);
        });
        this.$.changeText.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this.set("global.text", "count-" + this.count++);
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
<my-app></my-app>
```

Comment: Do you want to bind all headers to the same text content or do you want them to have their own content? Either way, you should probably use a [`dom-repeat`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-repeat) binded to an array property

Comment: Hi Alan. I'd like to bind any element to any property. A dom-repeat wouldn't help me here. Because I must define the template content within the dom-repeat. And I can't modify the template content on the fly.

Comment: Do you need two-way binding or is one way enough?

Comment: @Tomasz: Two-way would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I've almost got it by using `Polymer.Templatizer` behaviour. Unfortunately it seems that there is some bug or my mistake which prevents updates from parent from being applied to the dynamically created template. I'll raise an issue on GitHub.

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">

<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
 <paper-input label="global.text" value="{{global.text}}"></paper-input>
 <paper-button raised id="addHeadline" on-tap="addHeadline">Add Headline</paper-button>
 <paper-button raised id="changeText" on-tap="click">Change Text</paper-button>
 <p>global.text: &lt;{{global.text}}&gt;</p>
 
 <template if="true" is="dom-if">
   <div>      
  dom-if: <input type="text" value="{{global.text::input}}" />
   </div>
 </template>
  </template>
  <script>
 Polymer({
   is: "my-app",
   behaviors: [ Polymer.Templatizer ],
   properties: {
  global: {
    value: { text:'i' },
    notify: true
  }
   },
   ready: function() {
  this.count = 0;
  
        // this ensures that global.text is updated when text changes
  this._instanceProps = {
   text: true
  };
   },
   addHeadline: function() {
  
  this.template = document.createElement("template");
  var templateRoot = document.createElement('div');
  templateRoot.innerHTML = `<h1>{{text.text}}</h1><input type="text" value="{{text.text::input}}" />`;
        // you cannot just set innerHTML in <template>
  this.template.content.appendChild(templateRoot);
  
  this.templatize(this.template);
  var clone = this.stamp({
    text: this.global
  });

  // Append to my-app
  Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(clone.root);
   },
   click: function() {
  this.set("global.text", "count-" + this.count++);
   },
   _forwardInstanceProp: function(inst, p, val) {
  debugger;
   },
   _forwardInstancePath: function(inst, p, val) {
        // notify parent's correct path when text.text changes
  this.set(p.replace(/^text/, 'global'), val);
   },
   _forwardParentProp: function(prop, value) {
  debugger;
   },
   _forwardParentPath: function(prop, value) {
  debugger;
   }
 });

  </script>
</dom-module>
<my-app></my-app>
```

Comment: Hey @tomasz-pluskiewicz good idea. I tried also sth. similar and failed too :) In my try I skipped the templatize and stamp steps and just added a new template. This ended up in the same result.
I just guess that the additional element isn't added to the _nodes of the "outer" template and because of that there are no effects triggered for the newly created node.